# Mongo aggregation $group conditional $eq for string field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use Mongo v2.2.0.

I wrote the query but the main issue is $arrayElemAt. Standard replacement with $unwind-$first doesn't work for me and I suppose that better solution exists. I have a restriction to run this aggregation pipeline as a single operation instead of running a query for **positive** and **negative** data and later merge results in a code. I need to apply a $sort, $limit and $skip for the resulting query to restrict count of `words` to be used for filtering records from other collection and combine data from both collections in Java code.

Aggregation query:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "merchantId": ObjectId("59520e6ccc7a701fbed31f94"),
      "date": {
        "$gte": NumberLong(1389644800000),
        "$lt": NumberLong(1502409599999)
      },
      "isbn": "a123",

    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "word": 1,
      "sentence": 1,
      "type": 1,
      "date": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "word": "$word",
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "date": {
          $max: "$date"
      },
      "sentence": {
        $first: "$sentence"
      },
      "sentenceCount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },    
  },
  {
    $group: {
            "_id": "$_id.word",
            "word": { $first: "$_id.word"},
            "positiveCount": {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.type", "positive"]}, "$sentenceCount", 0]}},
            "count": {$sum: "$sentenceCount"},
            "positiveSentence": {
                "$push": {
                    "$cond": [{$eq: ["$_id.type", "positive"]}, "$sentence", "$noval"] 
                }
            },
            "negativeSentence": {
                "$push": {
                    "$cond": [{$eq: ["$_id.type", "negative"]}, "$sentence", "$noval"] 
                }
            }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "word": 1,
            "sentimentPercentage": {$cond: [{$eq: ["$count", 0]}, 0, {$multiply: [{$divide: ["$positiveCount", "$count"]}, 100]}]},
            "positiveSentence": {$arrayElemAt: ["$positiveSentence", 0]},
            "negativeSentence": {$arrayElemAt: ["$negativeSentence", 0]},
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
            sentimentPercentage: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  }
]
```

Collection document "schema":

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59887424e4b099e00724aa44"), 
    "merchantId" : ObjectId("59520e6ccc7a701fbed31f94"), 
    "isbn" : "a123", 
    "sentence" : "Great, friendly service.", 
    "word" : "service", 
    "type" : "positive", 
    "date" : NumberLong(1466809200000),    
}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
    "word" : "expectations", 
    "sentimentPercentage" : 100.0, 
    "positiveSentence" : "The service exceeded our expectations."
},
{ 
    "word" : "representative", 
    "sentimentPercentage" : 87.5, 
    "positiveSentence" : "Excellent local representative, met the flight and gave us all the relevant information to ensure a great holiday.", 
    "negativeSentence" : "The representative at resort was poor."
},
{ 
    "word" : "seats", 
    "sentimentPercentage" : 0.0, 
    "negativeSentence" : "Long delay and pre booked seats were lost ."
}
```

Please, could you advise me how to replace $arrayElemAt operator or even better how to optimise this query to the desired output using just features of Mongo <=2.2.0?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: @dnickless I've provided the sample of expected output

Answer (score 1):

This appears to give me reasonable results. I think it will not work properly, though, in cases where you have no positive or no negative sentence because of the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage which does not support the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` parameter in v2.2...

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "word": 1,
      "sentence": 1,
      "type": 1,
      "date": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "word": "$word",
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "date": {
          $max: "$date"
      },
      "sentence": {
        $first: "$sentence"
      },
      "sentenceCount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },    
  },
  {
    $group: {
            "_id": "$_id.word",
            "word": { $first: "$_id.word"},
            "positiveCount": {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.type", "positive"]}, "$sentenceCount", 0]}},
            "count": {$sum: "$sentenceCount"},
            "positiveSentence": {
                "$push": {
                    "$cond": [{$eq: ["$_id.type", "positive"]}, "$sentence", "$noval"] 
                }
            },
            "negativeSentence": {
                "$push": {
                    "$cond": [{$eq: ["$_id.type", "negative"]}, "$sentence", "$noval"] 
                }
            }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$positiveSentence" },
  { $group: 
      {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "word": { $first: "$word" },
          "count": { $first: "$count" },
          "positiveCount": { $first: "$positiveCount" },
          "positiveSentence": { $first: "$positiveSentence" },
          "negativeSentence": { $first: "$negativeSentence" },
      }
  },
  { $unwind: "$negativeSentence" },
  { $group: 
      {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "word": { $first: "$word" },
          "count": { $first: "$count" },
          "positiveCount": { $first: "$positiveCount" },
          "positiveSentence": { $first: "$positiveSentence" },
          "negativeSentence": { $first: "$negativeSentence" },
      }
  },
  {
    $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "word": 1,
            "sentimentPercentage": {$cond: [{$eq: ["$count", 0]}, 0, {$multiply: [{$divide: ["$positiveCount", "$count"]}, 100]}]},
            "positiveSentence": 1,
            "negativeSentence": 1
    }
  }
])
```

You might be able to simplify this further, e.g. get rid of the first projection and grouping stage. I can perhaps look into that in a few hours if you'd like me to.

Comment: Luckily, I've found out that we upgrade our db version to 3.4.4+. But I'm still interested how to solve this puzzle. Don't hurry, it'll wait